# How do I reference a local file when moving to a remote server?

Tags: python, plotly-dash, amazon-ebs

I’m trying to deploy my dash app on EBS. I currently reference a local directory (on my machine) as ‘C:\users\me\projects\superstar\assets\database.db’
My dash app.py is in the superstar folder. I’ve tried changing this to ‘/assets/database.db’, but the code is unable to find the file.

Comment: Remove the leading slash `assets/database.db` to make the path relative instead of absolute.

Comment: Is it correctly understood that you are trying to access files on the client, not the server?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the app.py file was not in the root directory.  Once I moved it there, accessing '/assets/database.db' worked fine.